# SAML Authentication with Firebase need to reauthenticate user every time

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, saml

I have a firebase project with firebase SAMLAuthentication, the method works fine but after the user insert credentials for is first time on the provider the browser will save it and on the next login he can access without need of re-insert his password.

I need everytime the user click on the login button he have to insert credentials.

I have already try [Auth Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) from documentation but seems not working for SAML

Also reauhenticateWithPopup() doesn't work.

There is other methods to set that?

here is my code:

```js
  const provider = new firebase.auth.SAMLAuthProvider('PROVIDER_NAME')
  
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log("ERROR: ", error)
  })
```